# How I do create new repository via gitosis + webdav

Tags: git, webdav, gitosis

I want to create new repository via http:// protocol.
so I installed gitosis + webdav on ubuntu.
I could clone and push from exsiting repository.
but, When I create new repository on local and remote add origin http:// ~ and push it,
I can not create new repository to server via http:// protocol.
but, I can create new repository to server via git protocol.

Can I create new repository using with http protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Gitosis and WebDAV do not work together in any way.

If you want HTTP access then you should use the `git-http-backend` cgi script. If you want ssh access control while only using a single system user like gitosis offers then you should use [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) which can be combined with the git-http-backend cgi script.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Can I create new repository use the git-http-backend? like "git remote add origin http://domain.com/example.git"